# Consultar en la DB un Query desde mi archivo conexion a DB

Tags: php7

[image: Este es el Codigo]

Me marca el siguiente error:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp64\www

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Las Imagenes suelen ser mal recibidas, en los links anteriores podras leer el por qué

Comment: Intenta agregar el código y no una imagen. Ahora, tu función `conexionBD()` no regresa nada, deberías darle al final de la función `return $enlace;` Con eso debería funcionar